# How to go to different section of a page in ionic?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Does anyone know the right syntax on how to go to a particular section on a page in ionic? I'm still trying to work my way with angular and ionic 4. This is my code and whenever I press the button that should direct me to section 2 of the current page, I end up going to a different page instead.

```
<div id="section1">
    //some content here
    <ion-button href="#section2>Next</ion-button>
</div>

<div id="section2">
    //some content here
    <ion-button href="#section3>Next</ion-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For this you will can use [scrollToPoint()](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content) method.

Declare a method in your component.ts file to get position of element:

```
export class SampleComponent {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  scrollTo(_id: string) {
      let y = document.getElementById(_id).offsetTop;
      this.content.scrollToPoint(0, y);
  }
}
```

Now bind this method to your scrollTo method and send section id where you want to scroll as argument.

```
<div id="section1">
    //some content here
    <ion-button (click)="scrollTo('section2')">Next</ion-button>
</div>

<div id="section2">
    //some content here
    <ion-button (click)="scrollTo('section3')">Next</ion-button>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, thank you!!!! But I had to change Content to IonContent because I get a "Cannot import module" error

Comment: Ohh yes! Content works with Ionic v3 and IonContent works with Ionic v4.